# Failed to get address of function SetDetourProvider from library

Tags: azure-devops, mstest

I have a Visual Studio solution with a mix of .Net Framework and one .Net Core project.
There are a series of UnitTest projects too (.Net Framework)

I am adding either an MStest or Xunit project to the Tests folder in the solution, and a few tests, and everything runs fine locally, but the AzureDevOPs Tasks set up to run the UnitTests starts to fail as soon as the MSTest or Xunit project get introduced. The failure generates the following stack trace:

```
Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.UnitTestIsolation.UnitTestIsolationException: Failed to get address of function SetDetourProvider from library 'D:\a_work\396\s\packages\microsoft.codecoverage\15.9.0\build\netstandard1.0\CodeCoverage\amd64\covrun64.dll'.

at Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.UnitTestIsolation.LibraryMethods.GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, String functionName)
at Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.UnitTestIsolation.LibraryMethods.GetFunction[T](IntPtr hModule, String functionName)
at Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.UnitTestIsolation.IntelliTraceInstrumentationProvider.Initialize()
at Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.UnitTestIsolation.UnitTestIsolationRuntime.InitializeUnitTestIsolationInstrumentationProvider()
at Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.Shims.ShimRuntime.CreateContext()
```

Are there any additional filters needed in the UnitTests task, to make this work?
This is my yaml for the task, the Xunit dll is excluded as it is a different file pattern, *unitXtests.dll :

```
steps:
- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'Test Assemblies: UnitTests'
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: |
     **\*unittests*.dll
     **\*integrationtest*.dll
     !**\obj\**
     !**\xunit.runner.visualstudio.testadapter.dll
     !**\xunit.runner.visualstudio.dotnetcore.testadapter.dll
    testFiltercriteria: 'TestCategory!=nonlocal'
    runOnlyImpactedTests: false
    vsTestVersion: 15.0
    runSettingsFile: src/Tests/test.runsettings
    overrideTestrunParameters: '-cert $(integration.cert)'
    runInParallel: false
    runTestsInIsolation: true
    codeCoverageEnabled: true
    testRunTitle: 'Unit Tests'
    platform: '$(build.platform)'
    configuration: '$(build.configuration)'
    diagnosticsEnabled: True
```

Comment: What's your local vs version, VS2017 or VS2019? I once reported similar issue when I encounter this error using VS2017, maybe you use VS2019 locally which has fixed the issue? If so, you should use 16.0 vsTestVersion instead of 15.0.

Comment: Thanks, I am using 2017 locally.

Comment: I once met similar issue and reported it [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/435236/unable-to-profile-test-when-using-fakes.html), I believe your issue may be related to code like `shimcontext.create()`. Since your solution have many test projects, maybe you need to firstly locate where the error comes from, I mean we need to check which project generates this error.